# Access Denied error on editing any profile?

Tags: users

I can't edit any profile from my admin account on Drupal, it says (Access Denied)
An other thing, any user can't edit their profile, same message (Access Denied)

How can I solv it?
I've enabled all permission..

Comment: do you have any 3rd party permissions modules active that could be overriding the core permissions?

Comment: Yes, I installed acl, node permission, content permission etc.

Comment: so... what happens if you disable those (not uninstall, just disable)?

Comment: Try to enable devel node access... maybe that will clear some things up.

Comment: I am also facing same issue